# How to exclude duplicate values ​taken from input checkbox and radio

Tags: html, jquery

I make multistep form and the last step is the summary step, in which I get values from the previous step and display. After clicking the summary button function getting values, but when somebody clicks previous and changing something values are duplicate. So my question is  How to exclude duplicate values ​​taken from input checkbox and radio?

```js
var wybraneProdukty = [];

$('input.produkty').change(function() {
  wybraneProdukty = [];
  
  $('input.produkty').each(function(i, item) {
    if ($(item).is(':checked')) {
      wybraneProdukty.push($(item).val());
    }
  });
  
  console.log("checkedAttr:", wybraneProdukty);
});

$('form #next_btn_jedzenie').click(function() {
  jQuery.each(wybraneProdukty, function(i, val) {
    $('#podsumowanie-produkty').append('<span>' + val + '</span></br>');
  });
  
  $('#podsumowanie-wejscia').append('<span>' + $("input[name=wejscie]:checked").val() + '</span>');
  $('#podsumowanie-toaleta-pracownicy').append('<span>' + $("input[name=toaleta_pracownik]:checked").val() + '</span>');
  $('#podsumowanie-toaleta-klient').append('<span>' + $("input[name=toaleta_klient]:checked").val() + '</span>');
  $('#podsumowanie-zmywalnia').append('<span>' + $("input[name=zmywalnia]:checked").val() + '</span>');
  $('#podsumowanie-jedzenie').append('<span>' + $("input[name=jedzenie]:checked").val() + '</span>');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple problems with the way your code is currently working.

First, you are adding the values of your checkboxes to the `wybraneProdukty` array when they are checked, but you are not removing them when they are unchecked. So your problem with duplicates will also happen when someone checks, unchecks, then re-checks an item.

From what I see in your code example, I think your may want to eliminate the `wybraneProdukty` array altogether and just work with the values of the inputs.

So in your button click handler where you currently have:

```
jQuery.each(wybraneProdukty, function(i, val) {
  $('#podsumowanie-produkty').append('<span>' + val + '</span></br>');
});
```

Change that to something like:

```
$('input.produkty').each(function(i, item) {
  if ($(item).is(':checked')) {
    $('#podsumowanie-produkty').append('<span>' + $(item).val() + '</span></br>');
  }
});
```

Comment: it append nothing

Comment: You didn't include enough of your code to determine what else might be going wrong, but here is a simple fiddle that shows the approach I describe: https://jsfiddle.net/zn7Lk1qa/